# Android: shuffling music - should I create a new service for every song?

Tags: android, service, media-player

I have an app which supports shuffling. I am not sure if I should create a new Service for every song and destroy the previous one?

Why I am thinking in this way is because currently I shuffle songs in one service with one media player. However, the song should stop somewhere in the middle and next song should start playing - but now I can hear them both although I have only one MediaPlayer. I suspect something is wrong with my fading in and out functions, but it would be easier to manage each track in it's own service.

Comment: Since there can only be one instance of a given `Service` implementation, I suspect that it will be much easier for you to have one `Service` and to use multiple `MediaPlayer` objects for your cross-fade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `SoundPool`. It looks like this:

`soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);`

Number 5 above mean that has maximum 5 streams can run concurrently. So. you just change 5 to 1.
And if you use others function. At constructor of its method, you should notice about parameter which name like `maxStream`

And, of course, something depend on your code, for example, if you do like that:

```
public void onSufftle(){
   String musicfile = Random(...); //your random algorithm to sufftle music
   AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
   AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd(musicfile);                   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),descriptor.getStartOffset(),descriptor.getLength());
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   mediaPlayer.prepare();
   mediaPlayer.start();
```

And of course, if your code like that, each new music is new service because you declare a new MediaPlayer instance.

So see your code carefully again :)

Comment: My service looks like this:
private MediaPlayer player=null;
...
player.create(myService.this, R.raw.soundfile1)

And when I play new music this method is called again only with different soundfile. In this case, do I have multiple services, for each new player.create() function??

Comment: Oh, yes, because you declare and instance a new MediaPlayer object each time sufftle. (like I say above). If you do that, you can repair by put your player at local scope. (and you can set it private properties if you want )

Comment: And when you don't use `MediaPlayer` again, use method `release` if not, many MediaPlayer instance will cause exception.

Comment: Wow, this is superweird. I'm still not sure if I understand correctly - If I define a global MediaPlayer, then started to play some song with it and while the songs play, if I assign another song to MediaPlayer, will the previous song still play? How can I then control old instances of MediaPlayer?